# C++ compiled with gcc is valid and invalid in VC++ 14

Tags: c++, visual-c++

If I compile and run the following code with gcc it works fine - and I don't see why this shouldn't. However if I compile and run this peace of code with VC++ it fails and a popup says:
"Expression: Vector iterators incompatible"

```
int main() {

    vector<int> v = { 1,2,3,4 };
    for(auto it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); )
    {
        if(*it% 2 == 0)
        {
            v.erase(it);
        }else
        {
            ++it;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Technically, the error (or rather, debug assertion) isn't raised by Visual Studio, or Visual C++. It is raised by it's debug runtime library.

Comment: [`it` will be invalidated](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/erase/) (see 'Iterator validity' section)

Comment: Unrelated to the error, have you considered using `std::remove_if` rather than a loop like this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

VC++ is right: `it` is invalidated when you call `erase`. You should probably use `it = v.erase(it)`. It works by coincidence under gcc.